# Is it possible to create a after login redirection?

Tags: orocommerce, orocrm

I'm currently looking for a way to create a page that would be the home page of an account after logging into my site.

Here's everything I looked at:

- Routing options with direct Url (which, after all, has nothing to do with what I'm looking for)
- Site map options
- I tried to find out if there was a way to modify the account settings page ( without result )

Impossible to find any documentation on the web.
I've even tried ChatGPT, but no good answer.

I'd like to point out that I don't have full access to the CRM and that, as a student, I don't know everything yet, which is why I've come to the forum for information.

Thank you in advance to anyone who can help me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The login form uses the standard Symfony approach, so you can change the redirect by following the Symfony documentation: https://symfony.com/doc/3.3/security/form_login.html.